# Can I train NER in spaCy using annotations from a wordpad or text document

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

Can I train NER in spaCy using annotations from a wordpad or text document, because training with a sentence or paragraph doesn't meet my requirements. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add more details on what your text document contains, and the type of annotations you have? If it's not sentences or paragraphs, what else do you want to train on?

Comment: My document will contain the following:

Comment: My document will contain descriptive specifications of say, a Product. So I would feed this wordpad text document (converted from a PDF) to the machine learning model to learn the entities and it's values. By this the ML model should be able to read any other products specification wordpad / text document and classify its entity/values. Eg: If it is a Paint product, it should be able to classify the entities/Values - Color - Dark Green, Temp - 40 F, Application method - Nylon Brush, Surface - Smooth layer, etc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
The python library [spacy-annotator](https://github.com/ieriii/spacy-annotator) is your friend here.
It uses ipywidgets to provide users with a user-friendly UI to annotate data.

**First**: install the annotator.

```
pip install spacy-annotator
```

**Second**, import your data from your txt document in a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('insert_text_file.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
```

**Third**, use spacy-annotator to label your data.

```
from spacy_annotator.pandas_annotations import annotate as pd_annotate

# Annotations
pd_dd = pd_annotate(df,
            col_text = 'full_text',     # Column in pandas dataframe containing text to be labelled
            labels = ['GPE', 'PERSON'], # List of labels you want to get from text
            sample_size=1,              # Size of the sample to be labelled
            delimiter=',',              # Delimiter to separate entities in UI
            model = None,               # spaCy model for noisy pre-labelling
            regex_flags=re.IGNORECASE   # One (or more) regex flags to be applied when searching for entities in text
            )
```

The cool thing is that the spacy-annotator (i) returns label in a format that spacy likes, (ii) it works with pandas orp python lists and (iii) allows users to do noisy pre-labelling (i.e. if you already have a spacy model, you can use it to get suggestions about which the entities to annotate).

If you prefer not to use pandas, you can always import each line of your text file in a python list and use the `spacy_annotator.list_annotations` module to do your annotations.
It works in a similar way.